# How to get the dual value of the constraint in GEKKO?

Tags: gekko

I have searched through the whole internet, not been able to find any solution yet.

My problem is a convex nonlinear program. For most convex solvers, it is the command

> *constraint.dual*

to get the dual value. Can I get dual values in Gekko?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual values are also known as Lagrange multipliers. Set `m.options.DIAGLEVEL=2` with a local solve `m=GEKKO(remote=False)` to access the dual variables.

```py
lam = np.loadtxt(m.path + '/apm_lam.txt')
```

Here is a test script.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#initialize variables
xi = [1,5,5,1]
x1,x2,x3,x4 = [m.Var(xi[i],lb=1,ub=5) for i in range(4)]

m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==40)

m.Obj(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)

m.options.DIAGLEVEL=2

m.solve(disp=False)

print('')
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(x1.value))
print('x2: ' + str(x2.value))
print('x3: ' + str(x3.value))
print('x4: ' + str(x4.value))

print('Lagrange multipliers')
lam = np.loadtxt(m.path + '/apm_lam.txt')
print(lam)
```

This produces the results:

```py
Results
x1: [1.000000057]
x2: [4.74299963]
x3: [3.8211500283]
x4: [1.3794081795]
Lagrange multipliers
[-0.55227642  0.16143862]
```

There is a similar question  [Lagrange multipliers (marginals) in Gekko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62040814/lagrange-multipliers-marginals-in-gekko) with additional comments. One of the important observations is that some solvers return the Lagrange multipliers while others don't report them. For example, solvers `m.options.SOLVER=2` (BPOPT) and `m.options.SOLVER=3` (IPOPT) return the dual variables while others `m.options.SOLVER=1` (APOPT) currently do not return them.